# Articles in captions. Do not use definite article

Tags: articles

I read in http://cdn.elsevier.com/promis_misc/cageogfamay.pdf :

Do not use the definite article („the‟) in figure or table captions. Why?

What is with „a/an‟?

Comment: I think they're probably just saying that if your paper includes, say, a chart showing historical price variations, your title / caption for the chart should be "Price of tea in China", not "**The** price of tea in China". In which case questions about using the ***indefinite*** article *(**a, an**)* don't really arise anyway.

Comment: It's the academic equivalent of 'headlinese'. Newspapers drop (among other things) many of the articles considered necessary in formal running prose to add punchiness. Academics do it in tables etc to convey conciseness.